# Need to achieve these 2 columns and two rows in a html Div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**Question:**
Need to adjust these grids by applying HTML and CSS. Tried but cant be able to adjust it in a single frame in a separate div. Made separate div including grids but unable to figure it out. Need to adjust it according to the picture shown below. Please help.
[![Implement this][1]][1]

Here is the HTML and CSS code I tried:
**html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    <script>
        src = "Javascript/javascript.js"
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Images/logo.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="text">
                <p>
                    Create your own board right now!
                </p>

                <div class="button">
                    <button type="button">Click Here!
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Home |
                </li>
                <li>
                    Create a Board |
                </li>
                <li>
                    Support Forums |
                </li>
                <li>
                    Board Directory |
                </li>
                <li>
                    FAQs |
                </li>
                <li>
                    Contacts



    </div>
    <div id="secondbodytext">

        <!--  <img id="bgimgid" src="Images/background.png" alt="">#region -->
        <img id="overimg1" src="Images/Screenshot from 2022-02-18 10-10-58.png" alt="">
        <div id="firsttextdiv">
            <p id="firsttextdiv">
                <img id="overimg2trans" src="Images/trans.png" alt="">
                Unlimited forams, categories „ and posts Private forums , Unlimited moderators. Surer moderators and
                administrators Access permissions and post permissions
            </p>


        </div>
        <img id="overimg2" src="Images/2nd.png" alt="">
        <div id="secondtextdiv">
            <p id="secondtextdiv">

                Personal image gallery Through a revolutionary „. </p>
        </div>
        <img id="overimg3" src="Images/3rd.png" alt="">
        <div id="thirdtextdiv">
            <p id="thirdtextdiv">
                <img id="overimg3trans" src="Images/trans.png" alt="">

                Thread count y Private messaging.
                Personal pone page style sheet wizard, you can create a truly unique layout
            </p>
            <img id="overimg1trans" src="Images/trans.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <img id="overimg4" src="Images/4th.png" alt="">
        <div id="fourthtextdiv">
            <p id="fourthtextdiv">
                Total psitors y Privacy setting y Change every image y Template system_ y y Total number at registered
                users Last user registered </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

.

```
container
{
  
    background-color: rgb(237, 241, 237);
}
.text
{
    background-color: rgb(251, 255, 251);
    float: right;
    font-size: larger;
   
    
}
.button{   
    float: right;
}
#bgimgid{
    
}
#overimg1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1600px;
    left: 190px;
    opacity: .7;
}
#overimg2
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1600px;
    left:550px;
    opacity: .7;
}
#overimg3
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1600px;;
    left: 900px;
    opacity: .7;
}
#overimg4
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1600px;
    left: 1200px;
    opacity: .7;
}

#thirdtextdiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 890px;
    left: 310px;
    color: white;
    font-size: medium;
}
#firsttextdiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 890px;
    left: 120px;
    color: white;
    font-size: medium;
   
}

#secondtextdiv{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: medium;
    top: 890px;
    left: 480px;
    color: white;
}

#fourthtextdiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 890px;
    left: 620px;
    color: white;
}

#overimg1trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}

#overimg2trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}
#overimg3trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}
#overimg4trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}
#overimg5trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}
#overimg6trans{
    position: absolute;
    top: 560px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    
    

}

#background img
{
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#secondcontainderdiv
{
width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

#navbar
{background-color: rgb(99, 93, 192);
    

}
#navbar ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: beige;
    font-size: larger;

 
}
#bodytext
{
  
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 760px;
   

}
#firsthead
{
    background-color: rgb(110, 100, 100);
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: larger;
   height: 30px;
   opacity: .7;
   padding: 20px;
   
    
}
#secondhead
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: larger;
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    padding: 20px;
    
}
#bodybutton
{ background-color: #4CAF50;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
}

#bodybuttonblue
{
    background-color: #4c5baf;
    font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: underline;
   margin-left: 920px;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: To expand on what Paulie said ~ "[An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/)" meaning if you try to position your the majority of elements like that, it will hardly be responsive. Which certainly is counterproductive to  Bootstrap (CSS framework directed at responsiveness). I suggest reading more into Bootstrap, then you can apply BS classes to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Please use The **CSS Flexible Box Layout Module**. Using Just couple of code you can achive this design.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style type="">
    .section-wrap{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
     
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #fff; flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .section-wrap > div{  flex-basis: 50%;}

    .imgBox { height: 300px; background: #eee;   display: flex; margin: 20px;
      align-items: center; justify-content: center;}

  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="section-wrap">

    <div class="section-div">
      <div class="imgBox"><img src="" alt="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
      <div class="imgBox"><img src="" alt="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
      <div class="imgBox"><img src="" alt="img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
      <div class="imgBox"><img src="" alt="img"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I insert this four image along with heading, text, and icons within these image Divs?

Comment: @PassionateProgrammer Yes - just differ the class names and set it as a background-image.

Comment: alright. THanks

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the example you shared, here's a quick sample code I generate using a flexbox;

The HTML;

```
<code>
       <body>
            <div>
                <h2 align="center">Recent Forums</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3> Announcements</h3>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3> Announcements</h3>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h3> Announcements</h3>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3> Announcements</h3>
                        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</code>


<code>
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px;
}
  
 .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
</code>
```